# Проблема с редактором Unity. Приложение не отвечает на клики

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Всем добрый день.

Возникла проблема с редактором Unity. Не получается взаимодействовать ни с иерархией, ни с Project-Animator-Console-Animation, ни с каким-либо другим окном. Когда нажимаю, например на вкладку Console, то просто ничего не происходит.

С оперативкой памятью проблем нет. Unity переустанавливал через Unity Hub.

[image: скрин 1]

Также, сам билд игры запускается и работает без каких-либо проблем. Проблема именно в редакторе, но я не понимаю, где вообще искать причину проблемы.

[image: Скрин 2]

За ответы спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Перезапуск, это основа решения всех проблем которые могут возникнуть в юнити, но вот Ваша проблема мне знакома, тоже такое было, после перезапуска у меня слетела лицензия в юнити хабе на версии 3.0.1, в итоге я откатил её на 2.45(забыл какая точно версия), ну а дальше схлопотал бан, но не об этом.

Comment: написанное как-то совсем на ответ не похоже.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я не могу добавлять комментарии из-за низкого рейтинга

Comment: чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin да, я знаю, спасибо, но увы немного не выходит их набрать.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась следующим образом:

- зашел в настройки лицензии в Unity Hub и сделал возвращение текущей лицензии
- Добавил бесплатную лицензию
- перезагрузил компьютер
- Unity Hub запуска через меню Пуск от имени администратора